# MYSQL Group Concat in a Procedure

Tags: mysql

I have a table like this below.table name=sample

```
id | product
--------------
1   | pen
1   | book
1   | eraser
2   | mouse
2   | keyboard
```

I want to have an output like this,

```
id | product
-------------
1  | pen,book,eraser
2  | mouse,keyboard
```

Got output by using group_concat. But, I need to have the same output through a procedure. Can someone help me? thanks in advance.

Comment: What's the problem? There's nothing special about using GROUP_CONCAT in a procedure.

Comment: i got from this select group_concat(product)from sample group by id; but i need this by creating procedure if 'n' number of lines available.

Comment: What difference is there if 'n' number of lines are available while using SQL and procedure ?

Comment: forget about that group_concat function. i need output like as i mentioned above by using procedure. could you help me?sorry for my bad english

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After reading your comments, i think you need help with procedure.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE `getdata`()
    BEGIN
        #Routine body goes here...
    select 
    id,group_concat(`product` separator ',')
    as Result from mytbl group by id;
    END;
```

All you have to do is simply

```
call getdata();
```

Comment: thanks..it's working well..but i think no need to use separator. it automatically  add a separator while calling group_concat. Is there any other method to get the output by using looping conditions etc etc..?

Comment: i did n't get you ? what do you mean by looping conditions?

Comment: getting the table by using select *from tablename and fetch it to another variable then checking line by line till and condition matches then concat it. i got that cleared which u mentioned above. but i need like this..thanks advance..sorry for my english.

Comment: It may take sometime. i will try to update the answer after sometime :)